# PSQL 8.3+ client query results display

Tags: postgresql, client, less-unix

Rather silly question, but I can't seem to find the answer in the docs or man pages.

Starting with 8.3 I think, the psql CLI client will not display the results of a large query inline. It pipes to a 'less-like' result viewer that disappears when you hit q.

This makes it very difficult to use data from the first query in subsequent queries or updates.

Does anyone know of a switch or way to force psql to display the query results inline, like the old client did?

edit: the \x switch does this, but I need the multiple row view.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`\pset pager off`

`\pset pager on`

`\pset pager always`

Alternatively, [configure the pager to your liking](http://merlinmoncure.blogspot.com/2007/10/better-psql-with-less.html).

Answer (score 4):

in addition to `\pset pager always` add the following in your .profile (or .bashrc)

```
export PAGER=less

export LESS="-iMSx4 -FX"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also disable it when you start up psql:

```
$ psql -U admin db_name --pset pager=off
```

If you *always* want it to be off, you can add this to your `.bashrc` file:

```
alias psql='psql --pset pager=off'
```

Comment: A better place to put this is in your `.psqlrc`, i.e.: `\pset pager off`